# Gas consumption of calling a view function from an other function

Tags: solidity, gas

I have a public `view` function that have a `for loop` inside of it, I put the loop inside the `view` function so I wont need to worry about the gas.

now my question is if I call the function internally from an other function that is not a `view` function will that create the possibility of high gas consumption (because of the `for loop`) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if you make a function a `view` function, you still have to pay full gas costs if it's being called inside a transaction. Such `view` functions are only free if called locally, not inside a transaction.

So, yes, you will have to pay for full processing of the function if called from a non-view function (inside a transaction).